# Simple If statement. Comparing non-numeric values

Tags: r, if-statement

My data:

```
pirmas      antras      trecias
    17          44           55
   788         890         1409
   968         218          344
   333         355           Na
```

I want to check which correlation is bigger:

- the correlation between pirmas and antras columns
- or the correlation between antras and trecias columns

Next, I want to write the `If statement`.
If the correlation between **antras** and **trecias** columns is bigger, I fill this N/A value in the last column with the value of the column antras.
BUT I get an error, because the function cor.test is test and does not give me a numeric answer, so I cannot compare them in If statement.

How can I do this?

My source code:

```
data<- X12_5_3
data
a<-cor.test(data$pirmas, data$trecias)
b<-cor.test(data$antras, data$trecias)

if (a<b) {
data$trecias[4]<-data$antras[4]  

}
data
```

Answer (score 2):

You can extract the correlation value from the test objects with `$estimate`.

```
set.seed(7)
a <- cor.test(rnorm(5), rnorm(5))
b <- cor.test(rnorm(5), rnorm(5))

if (a$estimate < b$estimate) {
  print('correlation of a smaller than b')
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need to do a **hypothesis test**, just use `cor()` to get their correlation coefficient. Besides, because of the presence of missing values, you need to control the argument `use` to deal with it.

```
a <- cor(df$pirmas, df$trecias, use = "complete.obs")
b <- cor(df$antras, df$trecias, use = "complete.obs")
```